# Dynamically added textbox with given value not added properly,jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added textbox value as `Baker's Basket, Pune, Maharashtra, Indiasd` but on click event in textbox it only shows `Baker's`

I want to display whole text `Baker's Basket, Pune, Maharashtra, Indiasd` in the textbox.

**[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/8/)**

```
// Try to Enter text given bellow 
//Baker's Basket, Pune, Maharashtra, Indiasd

$("#clk").on('click', function () {
    $("#cnt_div").empty();
    var getTxt = $("#txt_n").val();
    var addContent = "<input type='text' value=" + getTxt + " />";
    $("#cnt_div").append(addContent);
});
```

without editng **addContent**  variable

**Edited:**
**[JS FIDDLE SAMPLE TWO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/20/)**

```
$("#clk").on('click', function () {

    var gData1 = $("#txt_1").val();
    var gData2 = $("#txt_2").val();
    var gData3 = $("#txt_3").val();
    var cnt_1 = "<span class='lbl_normal_mode'>" + gData1 + "</span><input class='txt_edit_mode' value=" + gData1 + "  type='text'/>";
    var cnt_2 = "<span class='lbl_normal_mode'>" + gData2 + "</span><input class='txt_edit_mode' value=" + gData2 + "  type='text'/>";
    var cnt_3 = "<span class='lbl_normal_mode'>" + gData3 + "</span><input class='txt_edit_mode'  value=" + gData3 + " type='text'/>";

    var content_Data = "<div class='chunk_div_holder'><div style='float:left:width:100%'>" + cnt_1 + "</div><div style='float:left:width:100%'>" + cnt_2 + "</div><div style='float:left:width:100%'>" + cnt_3 + "</div></div>";
    $(".dynmic_cntt").append(content_Data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should better append the element and its properties dynamically as an object:

```
$('<input>', {
    type: 'text',
    value: $("#txt_n").val()
}).appendTo($("#cnt_div").empty());
```

This will solve the problem of extra spaces (no quotes for `value=Baker's Basket`), wrong string escape (if the value will have quotes) for `value` attribute and other caveats.

**N.B.:** There is no `textbox` type for `<input>` element. It should be `text` instead.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/11/

Comment: @VisionN: Thank you for reply, you answer worked, but am adding long data with more input tag along with some anohther element, so your answer will not fit in my case, any ohter option pls

Comment: @Satindersingh Please give an example of what *"long data"* you are trying to add. The best way will *always* be to set values to the elements as to objects and not in the string. In any case there is a way of doing this.

Comment: @Satindersingh For not overcomplicating the things I'd suggest to use [jQuery templates](http://www.jsviews.com/). But even in your case traversing and modifying objects' attributes is the best way to go: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/21/.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a better way of doing this...

```
var addContent=$("<input type='textbox' />").val(getTxt);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/9/

Basically, if creating an element to append to the DOM your better off doing this as a jQuery object. This way we can take advantage of methods such as val() for adding the value.

**UPDATE**

Ive simplified things a bit for you...

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/22/

```
$("#clk").on('click', function () {

    $('.dynmic_cntt').empty();

    $('.form-text').each(function(){
        var $div = $('<div style="float:left:width:100%;"></div>');
        var $span = $('<span class="lbl_normal_mode">'+ $(this).val() +'</span><input class="txt_edit_mode" value="'+$(this).val() +'"  type="text"/>');

        $('.dynmic_cntt').append( $div.append( $span ) );
    });

});
```

Comment: I like this way best as it would work with text that includes single and double quotes

Comment: you answer worked, but not in mu case, pls check my updated js fiddle, i dnt wnt to edit my addContent variable

Answer (score 1):

Add the field in two stages:

1. add the field as you are already
2. set the value of the field using .val()

Answer (score 1):

Value attribute should enclose in quotes. In your case, its better to use double quotes, because `Baker's Basket, Pune, Maharashtra, Indiasd` already have a single quote in it.

```
$("#clk").on('click',function(){
     $("#cnt_div").empty();
var getTxt=$("#txt_n").val();  
var addContent="<input type='textbox'  value=\""+getTxt+"\" />";
    $("#cnt_div").append(addContent);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/13/)

**Edit**

```
$("#clk").on('click',function(){
     $("#cnt_div").empty();
var getTxt=$("#txt_n").val();  
    var addContent=$("<input/>",{type:"text",value:getTxt});
    $("#cnt_div").append(addContent);
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/17/)**

Answer (score 1):

It is because you aren't escaping `'` single quote.
Instead you can replace

this line

`var addContent="<input type='textbox' value='"+getTxt+"' />";`

with

`var addContent=$("<input type='textbox' />").val(getTxt);`

or

`var addContent="<input type='textbox'  value=\""+getTxt+"\" />";`

Answer (score 1):

change `"+getTxt+"` to `'"+getTxt+"'`

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/16/)**

OR

change `"+getTxt+"` to `\""+getTxt+"\"`

Comment: this will only escape single quote, thus it will not append full entered text.